# how do i redirect to a welcome page from a html login form using javascript? The site is offline and on a development server

Tags: javascript, html

how do i redirect to a welcome page from an index page using javascript?
 The site is offline and on a development machine and not in a server www directory like (wamp, lamp, apache etc) .
 I would like to do it without using PHP, python etc cause I already know how it is done in php using header(location ... ).

The directory structure

---

site
 |
 |--img
 |--css
 |--index.html
 |--welcome.html
 |--error.html

I have already tried window.location, window.location.href  etc.
Inside the script of index.html.

```
if (true){
    self.location("welcome.html");
}
else{
    window.location.href = "error.html";
}
```

Comment: Why use "if (true) {...} else {...}" ??? true will always be true so you don't need the else or the if

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: window.location is the way to go, did you get any script errors?

Comment: self.location does not exist. That's it

Comment: as @frenchie said, your conditional logic is not correct for this purpose. try this 
   if(window.location.href == "file:///C:/path-to-site/index.html") {
         window.location = "file:///C:/path-to-site/welcome.html"
    }

Comment: A quick search brought up this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript

Comment: @edi9999 `self.location` does exist, `self === window`.

Comment: Right, didn't even know this

Comment: Hi Guys. Thanks for all your advice. But I was able to do it myself using window.location method. I found that the method was not the problem because I had tried it already previously. The problem was that the redirection happened but since the function "checkLogin" was called by the onsubmit function of html element form, it kept coming back to the same login page. I fixed it by returning false at the end of the checkLogin() script. But Thanks a ton for all your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Though Window.location is a read-only Location object, you can also
>   assign a DOMString to it. This means that **you can work with
>   window.location as if it were a string** in most cases: window.location
>   = 'http://www.example.com' is a synonym of window.location.href = 'http://www.example.com'.
>
> [Mozilla Docs -- Window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.location)

It is not a function but you can assign a string to it.

Just write:

```
window.location="error.html";
```

`self.location="error.html";` is fine too

Answer (score 0):

``This is very simple to do a page redirect using JavaScript at client side. To redirect your site visitors to a new page, you just need to add a line in your head section as follows:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
window.location="http://www.newlocation.com";
//-->
</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a meta-refresh redirect:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='welcome.html" />`

Or just do `window.location="welcome.html"` instead of `self.location("welcome.html")`

Comment: He would be unable to use the meta tag as it would do it all the time assuming he is not using a backend

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your advice.

But I was able to do it myself using window.location method. I found that the method was not the problem because I had tried it already previously.

The problem was that the redirection happened but since the function "checkLogin" was called by the onsubmit function of html element form,
 it kept coming back to the same login page.
 I fixed it by returning false at the end of the checkLogin() script.
 But Thanks a ton for all your input.